# C# deserializar enum que não existe

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Tenho uma classe que tem como atributo um Enum, por exemplo a classe car abaixo:

```
public enum Model { Volvo = 1, Ferrari = 2, Gurgel = 3 }

public class Car
{
    public Model model { get; private set; }

    public Car(Model model)
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Model), model))
            throw new Exception("Quero que arrebente esta exception");

        this.model = model;
    }

}
```

Se eu passar o Json certo para uma controller, uma instância da classe CAR será montada normalmente, porém, se eu passar o Json errado, o objeto da classe CAR ficará nulo e nem entrará no construtor. O certo não seria entrar no construtor independente do valor estar certo ou errado?

Json certo

```
{
  "model" : "Volvo"
}
```

Json errado

```
{
  "model" : "Arno"
}
```

Método da controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddCar([FromBody]Car car)
    {
        if (car == null) //CAI AQUI QUANDO O VALOR DO ENUM NÃO EXISTE.    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ler [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Ali mostra que o construtor serve para criar o objeto em estado válido. Se não existe o dado que deve ser usado então o objeto não pode ser criado. Se fosse pra criar um objeto de qualquer jeito então não precisava de construtor. E entrou no construtor, só que você lanou uma exceção e ele não foi construído (você pode mandar depurar pra ver passo a passo).

Mas mesmo nessa hipótese, o que você espera fazer com um objeto inválido? Só causar problema. Então o melhor que pode acontecer é o objeto ficar nulo e você só usá-lo depois de testar que ele está ok, que parece ser o que fez.

Claro pode ser que queira criar o objeto mesmo assim, mas aí no construtor dele tem que estabelecer o critério adequado para criar e conseguir um estado que seja sensível para o caso, pode até deixar em estado inválido, é errado, mas é algo tecnicamente possível, se você explicitar que quer isso, aceita. No caso nem vejo como deixar inválido. Se vier um `Arno` que valor o objeto deve ter então? Algum valor tem que ter, se você não colocar ele assumirá 0. O que fará com um modelo 0?

De qualquer forma, foi lançada uma exceção (de forma errada, mas foi), em algum deve ter capturado e aceitado o objeto assim mesmo, isso é errado, se teve uma exceção não pode continuar usando o objeto. Se quer usar assim mesmo a primeira coisa que tem que fazer é tirar a exceção (não estou dizendo que é certo fazer isso, mas se quer o objeto em estado inválido seria um pouco mais correto).

Comment: Você está sendo bem crítico com quem está tentando te ajudar. A pelo comentário parece que a pergunta não está clara então. Se você fez algo errado você quer que a pessoa diga que está certo? Então não quer ajuda. Não é possível fazer o certo com um enunciado de problema errado, você não pode falar que quer somar duas coisas e falar pra não considerar que tem uma soma. Eu respondi em cima do que escreveu, se queria escrever outra coisa deveria ter escrito essa outra coisa.

Comment: Rapaz...você está sendo bem crítico para alguém quem não entendeu nada da pergunta. 

1. Tudo que está aí em cima são exemplos, ou seja, não leve em consideração se estou levantando uma exception ou não num construtor. (eu sei muito bem para que serve o construtor, então sua recomendação é péssima)

2. A questão do VALOR do enum estar errado no JSON é justamente o x da questão, tendo em vista que o valor inválido não me deixa nem chegar no construtor do EXEMPLO car, provavelmente isso é na hora da desserialização do json no middle da controller.

Comment: o objeto da classe CAR ficará nulo e nem entrará no construtor. O certo não seria entrar no construtor independente do valor estar certo ou errado?

Essa pergunta é bem objetiva e sua resposta não tem nada ver com esta pergunta...ou seja, vc pouco interpretou!